# SQL Multiple Query with 1 Result Set

Tags: sql

This is really difficult to explain, but I'm going to take a shot.  Because it's hard to explain, it's also hard to search for - I have tried, and come up with nothing.

I'm trying to write on SQL statement, based on result set from two separate queries.

Query 1 returns student id, student lname, student fname from table1

Query 2 returns student id from table2

I didn't design the dB, but the queries have to be separate.  I have no choice there.

The result I want is, to return students from table1 only if their student id does not exist in table2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
select id, lname, fname from table1 t1 where t1.id not exists in (select id from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could get away doing something like this.  I apologize for any errors, but this is close to what you might need.

```
SELECT ID,LNAME,FNAME FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE 2)
```